# How to throttle/limit resources of webapps in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, resources, limit

I run several instances of the same webapp in Tomcat. I need to limit the

1. total bandwidth
2. memory
3. storage

used by each instance (webapp) in tomcat. Is there a way to do that in tomcat? If yes, how?

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

1. Bandwidth - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832512/how-to-throttle-webservice-calls-in-a-java-web-application) SO post. It only allows throttling based on request count (and not bandwidth) but still better than nothing.
2. I'm afraid this is not possible as you are running multiple webapps under the same JVM. There are some [papers](http://vmkit.llvm.org/publications/osgi_dsn.html) elaborating this should be possible if you use OSGi but I don't believe it is anywhere close to production-ready.
3. You are much better off achieving this using [OS disk quotas](http://www.udel.edu/topics/faqs/coplandquota.html) rather than programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, I'll have to use programs outside tomcat to throttle bandwidth and memory. One of the SO posts mentioned using multiple tomcat instances to limit memory use.

Comment: Yes, having multiple Tomcats is probably the best choice - but you mentioned that you use several instances of same app under one Tomcat so I thought this is not an option.